# SQL Server - Variable declared but still says "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run this set of SQL commands on Microsoft SQL Server but I am getting this error:

> *Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@dbstatus".*

I thought I did declare the variable so I'm not sure why it's still throwing the error?

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(100) 
DECLARE @dbstatus varchar(500) 
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000) 
create table #temptable (dbname nvarchar(100), status varchar(500))

DECLARE c1 CURSOR READ_ONLY 
FOR 
   SELECT '[' + name + ']'   FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'EDDS1084543'

OPEN c1  
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @dbname 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN            
      SET @sqlCommand = 'SET @dbstatus = (SELECT Status FROM ' + @dbname + '.[EDDSDBO].[dtSearchIndex])'   

      EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand

      INSERT INTO #tempTable(dbname, [status])VALUES (@dbname, @dbstatus)

      FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @dbname   
END   

CLOSE c1 
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EXEC/sp_executesql creates a new connection (SPID) to the SQL Server, which is not your current session, so it cannot see the variable.  Check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Basically, you have to declare the parameter you want to pass into the call, and give it a value.  In this case, both have to include the OUTPUT specifier.

```
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, '@dbstatus varchar(500) output', @dbstatus output
```

Comment: If I'm only using a procedure to take three(3) `date` params and then return a table based on that, how would I use the three different parameters?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
  SET @sqlCommand = 'SET @dbstatus = (SELECT Status FROM ' + @dbname + '.[EDDSDBO].[dtSearchIndex])'   
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

This causes the server to execute the value of `@sqlCommand` as a standalone statement. Within this statement, `@dbstatus` has not been declared as a variable, hence the error. This is what's getting executed:

```
SET @dbstatus = (SELECT Status FROM [value in @dbname].[EDDSDBO].[dtSearchIndex])
```

Try this instead:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN            
      SET @sqlCommand = 'SET @dbstatus = (SELECT Status FROM ' + @dbname + '.[EDDSDBO].[dtSearchIndex])'   
      EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, '@dbstatus varchar(500) output', @dbstatus output
      INSERT INTO #tempTable(dbname, [status])VALUES (@dbname, @dbstatus)
      FETCH NEXT FROM c1
      INTO @dbname   
END
```