# SQLFiddle: must declare the scalar variable error

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to execute next SQL statement (SQL Server 2008 Profile)

```
DECLARE @fun int;
SET @fun = 40;

select cast(@fun as varchar(10)) + 'hello'
```

and SQLFiddle gives me the error: `Must declare the scalar variable @fun`

Where I'm wrong?

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the semicolons are introducing the problem here.

As described here: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-137.aspx and here: [SQL Server - Variable declared but still says "Must declare the scalar variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750548/sql-server-variable-declared-but-still-says-must-declare-the-scalar-variable), the problem arises when the statements are executed individually instead of as a “unit”, and the semicolons seem to trigger that.

When I remove the semicolons from your statement, it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42159

Comment: While this works in this simple case, it is [not exactly a best practice](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx), and will break when the OP uses a query construct that actually requires semi-colons.

Answer (score 10):

You need to select the [Go] from last dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to remove the semicolons, the important part is select [GO] as query terminator on the bottom right conner dropdown.

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2027)

```
DECLARE @fun int;
SET @fun = 40;
select @fun;
GO

select 10;
GO

select @fun + 10;
```

The first three sentences are executed as a whole because now `;` doesnt end the query. So @fun is visible on that scope.

Second block take notice you need leave a space after GO.

Third block wont work because @fun isn't define in this block.